# PHPUnit: assertion on splat operator argument

Tags: phpunit

I have an issue with checking the argument of function when it is declared as splat:
Example:

```
class Client
{
    public function __construct(
        private Server $server
    ) {}

    public function get($array): void
    {
        $this->server->get(...$array);
    }

}
```

```
class Server
{
    public function get(int ...$id): string
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Test:

```
    public function testExample(): void
    {
        $serverMock = $this->createMock(Server::class);

        $sut = new Client($serverMock);

        $serverMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('get')
            ->with(self::callback(function (int ...$id) {
                self::assertEquals([1, 2, 3, 4], $id);
                /**
                 * $id = [1]
                 */
            }));

        $sut->get([1, 2, 3, 4]);
    }
```

In this case, $id = [1] and the assertion fails.

however, this assertion works just fine:

```
$serverMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('get')
            ->with(...[1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to do it properly.
Of course, this is just an example of the issue - in real life args are not integers, but complex objects and I don't want to construct them all - this is why I need to use callback.